# 'JsonConvert' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Newtonsoft.Json'

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm getting this error even though only on version is installed in the project (13.0.1)

any ideas?

Errors:

```
1>C:\Users\boruc\source\Workspaces\BinaNew3\BinaNewWebApp\admin\SiteSettings.aspx.vb(36,20): error BC30560: 'JsonConvert' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
```

1>C:\Users\boruc\source\Workspaces\BinaNew3\BinaNewWebApp\Old_App_Code\EmailService.vb(26,33): error BC30560: 'JsonConvert' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Newtonsoft.Json'.

Code

```
Imports Newtonsoft

 Dim jStr = Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nEmailSetting)
```

Here's object explorer snapshot showing 2 references to Newtonsoft

[image]

Comment: If you press F12 when the JsonConvert is selected, it is shown where the class is in the project? - right click > search all references

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre]?

Comment: F12 says ' Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret.'

Comment: can you show more details of the error when you compile the solution, please?

Comment: @boruchsiper thank you. In the screenshot I saw 2 Newtonsoft instances: 6.0 and 13.0 , would be possible remove one of them?

Comment: Updated question with additional info

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Don't know how to remove the 6.0.0 reference. Tried reinstalling newtonsoft. didn't help

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry about that. Updated q with more info.

Comment: @boruchsiper I'm not familiar with vb.net, but, check the references of the project [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqHrF.png), right click on the Newtonsoft 6.0 version and select "remove";  if not, then, check the web.config (*or the file where the Newtonsoft is declared*) and see where it is used the 6.0 version, then, remove those lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244524/discussion-between-marco-aurelio-fernandez-reyes-and-boruchsiper).

Answer (score 1):

1- you should rebuild the solution after removing the the old Newtonsoft.Json version.

2- change this line of code from :

```vb
Dim jStr = Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nEmailSetting)
```

to

```vb
Dim jStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nEmailSetting)
```

3- your IDE will give you a hint to import the correct namespace which is Newtonsoft.Json.